# How to get the current logged in userId with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to get the current logged-in userId. How can I do this with plain JavaScript?

I can do it with a get request that uses security claims in the backend with c#, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the way how login is implemented... Assume that you use API's and JWT. So usually when you log in, you get a JWT assigned, it can already hold some of those details (depends on the end-point what you get). Use http://jwt.io and you'll see. There are then tools in the JavaScript world to decode a JWT and get those data. Anyhow, if you do a single additional call, then cache the result, that is just as fine, IMO. Also you usually store JWT in a localStorage or so, so those data are avail. all the time...

Comment: My login is implemented using Identity.

Comment: This is a .NET Identity approach that issues a JWT, which is the used on the JavaScript to auth. against the API. That what's in the JWT is controlled by the .NET login, I do extend it with some roles. Sample is free accessible: https://github.com/hidegh/Meal-tracker

Comment: .NET https://github.com/hidegh/Meal-tracker/blob/master/RMeals-server-dotNet/src/RMealsAPI/Features/AuthenticationController.cs#L44 --- Angular: https://github.com/hidegh/Meal-tracker/blob/0463cfd520d15b3c82e10497695556aea84a3229/RMeals-client-angular/src/app/_auth/auth.service.ts#L79